# How to make div draggable with other div on top of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, positioning, display

I have two `div` on top of eachother. One is to display a border and the other is to display an image. I'm using the jquery `.draggable();` method to make the div underneath draggable. The problem is that I can not move the `div` underneath. If it is on `display:none;` the draggable method works fine. It's because there is a div on top of it.

HTML:

```html
<div id="editor-holder">
   <div id="border-holder"><img src="img/border.png"></div>
   <div id="image-holder"><img src="background-image.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#editor-holder{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#border-holder{
  position:absolute;
}
#border-holder img{
  width:100%;
}

#image-holder{
  position:absolute;
}
#image-holder img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
$( function() {
   $( "#image-holder" ).draggable();
});
```

I want to be able to drag the background image around without having to hide the border. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none` to the CSS for the border element. It will make it untargetable and all click/drag/touch events will pass through it .